# Declare getIndex method in the child class with different parameters

Tags: php, class, laravel, inheritance

I'm using Laravel, and I have a class that extends its parent; however, when I try to declare a `getIndex(Request $request, $id)` function in my child class, it complains that `Declaration of getIndex() should be compatible with parent class`.

I realize that my parent class only declares it as `getIndex()` with no parameters, and I really don't need to pass any parameters in the parent class either. How can I workaround this issue? Is this something that needs to be handles via `namespace`?

```
class WorkersController extends BaseController
{
    public function getIndex(){}
}

class WorkersFilesController extends WorkersController 
{
    // Gives me an error
    public function getIndex(Request $request, $id){}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing your parent class (or its parent class) is declared as `abstract`? That's what is requiring you to be compatible. If it's a normal class (not abstract) you can change the method signature.

Comment: Yes, parent's parent class is declared as abstract. I don't think I can change it, as it's currently being used across the applications and all the controllers are extending it.

Comment: Then you have to be compatible. No way around it. Either figure out how to write your function without arguments, or rename the function to be unique.